# jasmine vs jasmine-node test differences

Tags: jasmine, jasmine-node

I have been using jasmine and today I thought I would try jasmine-node. Some of the passing tests for jasmine fail in jasmine-node.  Specifically, toBeLessThanOrEqual is not a function in jasmine-node.   Is jasmine-node something that should be avoided?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference is the version of `jasmine` that is being used. With `jasmine-node` they use version 1.3.1 currently, while `jasmine` itself is much further along (currently at version 3.2).  Since `jasmine` has had a couple of major version changes, there are breaking changes between them which explains why your tests that use `jasmine` 2.x or 3.x might not work with `jasmine-node` because the syntax is different.

Until `jasmine-node` updates to use a newer version of `jasmine` you would be stuck with the `jasmine` 1.x syntax, which isn't great.

Note that if you want to use `istanbul` for code coverage you'd also have to force it to used the same `jasmine` version that your tests are written with.

While `jasmine-node` can be convenient, I prefer to use the latest `jasmine` syntax so can't use it as it is.